# Why is every other ping to my wifi router taking a long time?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

If I ping my wifi router, I get:

```
C:\>ping 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64              <--- Quick
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=544ms TTL=64            <--- Long delay
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64              <--- Quick
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=545ms TTL=64            <--- Long delay
```

The 'long' time varies each time I do a ping (from around 300ms to over a second), but the results *always* follow the same pattern, where every other ping time will be very long (and by almost the same delay).

**Client:** Windows 7 64bit desktop with onboard Reaktek wireless NIC RTL8191SE

**Router:** Linksys WRT54G running Tomato v1.28.1816

This is *not* happening with my laptop, which shows normal ping results to the router.

I'm connected over 802.11G and have 'excellent' signal strength according to windows (-64dBm according to inSSIDer).

**Any idea what might be going on here?**
**Is there any software which can help diagnose the problem?**

Answer (score 2):

I had various issues with tomato firmware, none of which could be easily rectified. What I had to do was to install the original firmware again (linksys) then in the firmware do a reset to factory settings, and then upon rebooting upload the Tomato firmware again. Don't restore from backup, manually do the settings. The Tomato Shibby builds seem to work best. My router would randomly not allow access to the setup, and experience pings like yours, even when another computer wouldn't experience this. Pickup a cheap USB Wifi adapter for your laptop and try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

When the issue is not with all the machines, then the issue is specific to the effected machine alone and not a generic issue to analyze with other devices.

Have you tried Uninstalling and Installing the Ethernet drivers?.
From the Network properties window, Disable and Enable the Network Adapter
Check and disable any security software's (Firewall & Antivirus), probably this can also cause the issue.
Change the network card and isolate the issue in the desktop pc

Comment: Thanks, yeah I assume the problem is with the PC.  The Wireless NIC is on the motherboard, so no possibility to change that, but will try reinstalling the drivers.